# need help in creating sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry guys but SQL amateur here, if you can help please.

The problem is i need to change all CurentID's to a new ID and there are multiple CurrentID's for the same people, so i am trying to make them use just 1 CurrentID but i cannot have duplicate key values on CurrentID but i can on PersonID so i here is the logic i think it should do.Hope its not too confusing.

**THE QUERY**

If CurrentID = OldID change to NewID

If NewID is taken, change PersonID to the PersonID of the person with that taken NewID

**Table1**

PersonID

CurrentID - PK

**Table2**

OldID

NewID

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming  you have this data in a table already?  If so, why not create a new table that has the ID as an auto_increment field.

New table structure:

```
CurrentID int auto_increment primary key
PersonalID int
```

Then use this query to populate the new table:

```
Insert into NEW_TABLE (PersonalID) select PersonalID from OLD_TABLE;
```

The CurrentID will be given assigned a unique value automatically.

Comment: Yes data is in there, CurrentId has to be changed to the values in NewID